# How to Get All the Containers From a Specific Azure Storage Account using Azure CLI?

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

How to Get All the Containers From a Specific Azure Storage Account using Azure CLI?
How to set context in azure cli like we set context in Powershell?
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

How can we achieve this using Azure CLI?

### Get the storage account from which container has to be retrieved

### Get the storage account context

### List all the containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get All the Container list

```
az storage container list --account-name <Storage Account Name> --account-key <Storage Account Key> --query "[].{Name:name}" --output table
```

[image]

#### Set & Get Context

```
# example to set the Az context
Set-AzContext -Subscription  "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
```

Refer [Set AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-7.4.0) & [Get AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-7.4.0)